# Is there any problem if the same app is submitted twice in the Play Store?

Tags: android

The thing is, I need to update an Android App but I don't have the credentials to do that, so I was wondering if I could submit the same app to have whole control on it. The app is connected to a server, so I don't know if both apps can be connected without problem.

Comment: You have to use a different packageName in AndroidManifest.xml than the original app.

Comment: Thanks for answering!, I'll check it as you say.